# ObjectInputStream read in a .dat file directly from URL

Tags: java, url, objectinputstream

I am new at Java and English.

I have this .dat file in URL written using `ObjectOutputStream`.

**How can I read it directly from the URL without having to save the file to my computer?**

The first thing written in a file is a number the rest is text. I got the number, I need to get the rest. There should be four more lines in that file as it is said in the task (which is too irrelevant here).

I got this code, which gives me a number = 4

```
ObjectInputStream input2 = new ObjectInputStream(
            new URL("http://www.ut.ee/~marinai/sulearvutid.dat").openConnection().getInputStream());
    int number=input2.readInt();
    System.out.println(number); 
    // prints 4
```

It now seems that I have solved the issue, big thanks to Paul and EJP. What I needed was

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.ut.ee/~marinai/sulearvutid.dat");
    ObjectInputStream input2 = new ObjectInputStream(
            url.openConnection().getInputStream());

    int number=input2.readInt();
    System.out.println(number); //prints 4

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufPos;
    InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();

    for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
        String b = input2.readObject().toString();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

Comment: ***Forget about the `BufferedReader.`*** You said yourself in comments that the data was produced by `ObjectOutputStream.` That makes `ObjectInputStream` your only choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObjectInputStream` is supposed to read `Object`s via `readObject()`. You can just aswell read integers from the stream, but i don't see any use in that - atleast not for your purpose.

Either the direct way:

```
URL url;//init with your url
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufPos;
InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

while((bufPos = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
    builder.append(new String(buffer , 0 , bufPos));

is.close();

return builder.toString();
```

Or, if you want to read by lines:

```
URL url;//init with your url
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    builder.append(line);

is.close();

return builder.toString();
```

Comment: What? I don't understand. I need to get strings from that file.

Comment: I want to get the text of that file. I viewed the file with Excel, it showed some weird symbols...

Comment: text can simply be read from the inputstream itself as `byte[]`, or linewise with a `BufferedReader`. but whats the purpose of the file `.dat` is most likely **not** meant to be humanreadable

Comment: This is a part of the task, that file has to be .dat type. A simple example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: i've added examples for reading the content with a bufferedreader and the inputstream from the connection

Answer (score 0):

**Of course** it threw a `NullPointerException.`
Try *initiliazing* the byte array.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; // or whatever length you're expecting to read
```

And don't use `available()` as a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. That's not what it's for.

I don't see anything here that requires an `ObjectInputStream.`

Comment: Is there any other efficent way to get the info(text/numbers) from a file that was written with ObjectOutputStream?
Oh and I don't know the lenght if the byte array aswell.

Comment: You read it with the converse of the methods you wrote it with. You *should* use `writeObject()` for everything, and read it with `readObject().`

Comment: I wasn't the one who created this file. Please understand that I am a mere peasent in java (yet) and I find your explantions very complex.

Comment: Come off it. What exactly is complex about iniitalizating a byte array, or 'don't use `available()`', or 'use `writeObject()` for everything, and read it with `readObject()`'?